# RelativeLayout all programmatically not aligning correctly

Tags: java, android, button, layout, textview

Below is the code and layout it is producing.

```
public void level1() {

    tList = getTList(level);
    bList = getBList(level);

    // textviews
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params00 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(buttonDimension, buttonDimension);
    gameplayRL.addView(tList[0], params00);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params11 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(buttonDimension, buttonDimension);
    params11.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tList[0].getId());
    gameplayRL.addView(tList[1], params11);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params22 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(buttonDimension, buttonDimension);
    params22.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tList[0].getId());
    gameplayRL.addView(tList[2], params22);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params33 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(buttonDimension, buttonDimension);
    params33.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tList[2].getId());
    params33.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tList[0].getId());
    gameplayRL.addView(tList[3], params33);

    // buttons
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(buttonDimension, buttonDimension);
    gameplayRL.addView(bList[0], params1);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(buttonDimension, buttonDimension);
    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, bList[0].getId());
    gameplayRL.addView(bList[1], params2);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(buttonDimension, buttonDimension);
    params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, bList[0].getId());
    //params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, bList[0].getId());   // this is the problem line
    gameplayRL.addView(bList[2], params3);
}
```

[image]

Notice the line 3 from the bottom that is commented out.  The button that is labeled "3", I want to be underneath the "2".  When I uncomment that line of code, the below layout happens.

[image]

I would think by uncommenting that line, it would just align that button over to the right but it screws the whole layout out of wack.  How can I achieve what I am looking for?

**EDIT**

Even using this code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(buttonDimension, buttonDimension);
        params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tList[2].getId());
        params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tList[0].getId());
        gameplayRL.addView(bList[2], params3);
```

...produces this layout:

[image]

So this is close but still not exactly the desired output.

Comment: Why have you got the TextViews?

Comment: @Squonk they are purely for testing purposes.  They will not be in the eventual final product.

Comment: First, your 3rd image is exactly the same as the 1st. Second, the 2nd layout is only messed up because you have the 4th TextView in there which is forcing parent layout to expand horizontally to accommodate it.

Comment: I know the 1st and 3rd image are the same.  I was just showing 2 separate snippets of code were both producing the incorrect layout.  And also, 1st and 3rd images also have the 4th TextView so why aren't those parent layouts being expanded horizontally like the 2nd image?